# How to embed inline C++ syntax in another language definition?

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I have a custom Perl syntax file for Sublime Text 3 and I would like to add an highlighting support for embedded C++ code.

The  `inline C++`  code always starts with  `__CPP__`  and ends with  `__END__`   among the perl code.

I'm using the 'embed/match/escape' approach but the syntax highliting of the C++ code won't change (getting the scope with ctrl-alt-shift-p it still appears as `source.perl`).

Here the rule I'm using in my syntax file:

```yaml
    contexts:
       main:
         - include: inline-cpp
          ...lot of rules...
       
       inline-cpp:
         - match: '__CPP__'
           embed: scope:source.c++
           embed_scope: source.c++.embedded
           escape: '__XXX__'
```

Please could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved putting the `include` in `prototype` section instead of `main` :

```yaml
   contexts:
       main:
           ...
       prototype:
         - include: inline-cpp
       inline-cpp:
         - match: '__CPP__'
           embed: scope:source.c++
           embed_scope: source.c++.embedded
           escape: '__XXX__'
```